# Angular Material Dark Color Palette

Tags: css, angularjs, android-theme, color-palette, angular-material

I have started using Angular Material in my application.  It is very nice to use and makes things easy to implement but I am having issue with the custom color palettes.

I am wondering if anyone has themed a dark theme for Angular Material?

I was looking at using this:

https://material.angularjs.org/#/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just asking for a Dark Theme is too board and completely opinion based, as to the primary color used and the variance in colors. This is not a question so much as asking someone to do design work for you for free.